# Css modules not working on production build

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, production

I am currently working on a project where I'm using css modules for each component and for pages containing the components. Apart from this I have a main index.css which just has the layout css and nothing else . I'm using bootstrap and react bootstrap apart from this. When I run npm build I notice that the react bootstrap is loaded but the module.css that I coded isn't, so my page looks horrid without styles. Can you offer any pointers on how I should proceed? Note: it's working perfectly fine running a server on 3000 on npm start and it is only on production that this happens. I am not using any specific webpack.config.js

Comment: Check your console and look for error messages. We can only guess since you haven't provided any code or anything.

Comment: console does not show anything regarding css , should I consider using a bundler like webpack?

Comment: If it doesn't work without a bundler, it's not going to work with one.